# Return how much data grouped by in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following Ruby code which groups JSON data into months:

```
  data = data.group_by { |d| d['Date'].to_date.strftime('%Y-%m') }
             .collect { |k, v| {Date: k, Total: v.sum { |d| d['Total'].to_i }} }
```

So for example it will change:

```
{"Date":"2012-04-01 12:00:00","Total":"50"},
{"Date":"2012-04-01 13:00:00","Total":"50"},
{"Date":"2012-04-02 05:00:00","Total":"100"},
{"Date":"2012-04-02 06:00:00","Total":"100"}
```

Into:

```
{"Date":"2012-04","Total":"300"}
```

But I'd like to know how many days were grouped into the new JSON.

So again in my above example, I'd want to return:

```
{"Date":"2012-04","Total":"300","Days":"2"}
```

Edit: I accidentally thought I wanted the total items grouped originally, but I've edited this question, as what I really want to know, is the total days grouped into the month (as some months might not have data for all the days so I want to know how complete the month is).

**The data always comes as hourly! So don't need to worry about minutes or seconds.**

Comment: change `{Date: k, Total: v.sum { |d| d['Total'].to_i }` to `{Date: k, Total: v.sum { |d| d['Total'].to_i , Grouped: v.size}`

Comment: yep, just add the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that group_by returns a hash where the **keys are evaluated result from the block, and values are arrays of elements in enum corresponding to the key**, then your collect received a |k,v| where the k is the month and v is an array of items in that month.

You can use that to change you code like this:

```
data = data.group_by { |d| d['Date'].to_date.strftime('%Y-%m') }
           .collect { |k, v| {Date: k, Total: v.sum { |d| d['Total'].to_i }, Grouped: v.count} }
```

---

## Updated answer

Ok, based on your comments, here's my updated answer. This code works but it is not the most elegant. There might be a better way to achieve this. But I hope this can help you anyway.

```
totals = {}
data2 = data.group_by { |d|
  day = d['Date'].to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  totals[day] ||= 0
  totals[day] += 1
  d['Date'].to_date.strftime('%Y-%m')
}.collect { |month, values|
  {
    Date: month,
    Total: values.sum { |d| d['Total'].to_i},
    Grouped: totals.group_by{|day, v| day.to_date.strftime('%Y-%m')}[month].count
   }
}
```

This keeps track of each day in a separate hash `totals` and then count the days in a specific month.

---

## Slightly more elegant

```
days = []
data2 = data.group_by { |d|
  day = d['Date'].to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  days << day
  d['Date'].to_date.strftime('%Y-%m')
}.collect { |month, values|
  {
    Date: month,
    Total: values.sum { |d| d['Total'].to_i},
    Days: days.uniq.select{|day| day.to_date.strftime('%Y-%m') == month}.count
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean items. I've just updated my question. What I really meant was how many days were being grouped into the month. As my JSON contains times so you could have 1000's per month. So getting the count wouldn't be correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Cameron, in this case, the number of items is the number of days, no? That's what I see anyway. Try this code and see if you get the expected results and compare with a manual count. You'll see its the same.

Comment: No, because I might have several objects per day day for different times. So the count would be on every hour rather than every day for that month.

Comment: @cameron Then you should change your sample data to reflect that. For example, add `{"Date":"2012-04-01 13:00:00","Total":"50"}` which is same day, different hour and different total. right?

Comment: Cool, that works :) I'll have a play with that. Thanks!